# Create c# code under linux

Tags: c#

Lately I used a lot of C# for Windows. I am trying to stick with C# and create C# applications under Ubuntu 11.

The problem is that I was so use to editor that I did not learn how to create elements under code only.

Could anyone point me in direction where I can find a solution on how to create windows, labels, textboxes etc. just by using code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install MONO under Linux, and complie C# program with MONO and run it.
This information is about **What's MONO**.
http://www.mono-project.com/What_is_Mono

To compile and install MONO, you can reference [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono), and [this is about how to use IDE to develop MONO application under Linux](http://monodevelop.com/).

Although MONO can help you run .NET/C# application under Linux, you still need to consider the following things when migrating the application.

- Linux is Case sensitive but Windows is not. Some code need to read ini or xml file, you need to ensure the file name is correct in the Linux program.
- Directory structure is different, such as C:\Windows and /etc/, you need to ensure that the code references the correct locations
- Some XML configuration information needs to be re-tested to ensure compatibility.
- Do a high coverage test to ensure every function works properly
- Security environment is different between Linux and Windows, and this may have an impact on the application

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean an IDE? [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is probably what you want.

As of 2.4, I believe it comes with WinForms Designer, which will help you build your forms.

If that doesn't work, you can use [WinForms Designer](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms_Designer) itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not doing that, and instead using an IDE on Linux.  In particular [Eclipse with Emonic and NAnt](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-migratenetvs/) or [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) should work well for you.

To be perfectly honest C# Winforms was not designed to be written by hand.

Comment: Not doing *what* excactly?  If you are referring to @Vivin Paliath's answer, then you should explicitly say so and link to the answer.

Comment: I want details!  Simple editing didn't helping me with understanding C in detail.

Comment: @casperOne @HelpNeeder I'm suggesting not editing GUI code by hand.  It's not a very good use of time IMO.